# how to do clean apache2 installation

Tags: macos, apache

I have messed out a lot of things with currently installed apache. It doesn't work at all. So, I want to delete apache completely and re-install everything. I want to do completely clean installation. How would I do it?

OSX version: Yosemite

Package Manager: Homebrew

Comment: You probably don't have to re-install it. It is probably a configuratin error in httpd.conf or a missing library.  Can you tell us what error messages you get or what your log says?

Comment: $ sudo apachectl configtest
Password:
@Allan
httpd: Syntax error on line 493 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 16 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf: No matches for the wildcard '*.conf' in '/private/etc/apache2/users', failing (use IncludeOptional if required)
$

Comment: Can you post your httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an external command called brew rmdeps or brew rmtree.

To install and use, issue the following commands:

```
$ brew tap beeftornado/rmtree && brew install brew-rmtree
$ brew rmtree <package>
```

You can view the full discussion on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7323261/4703819).